# Is there any easier way to navigate functions in komodo?

Tags: komodoedit

I'm working with komodo but i cant seem to find an easy way to navigate between functions. Say i have a source file that is starting to get long and i have to navigate from line 305 to line 15 several times and i have to scroll back and forth..

After reading documentation and searching on google i found the "Find all functions" menu item but that only lists the functions at the bottom and if there is many functions the window is too small and i also have to scroll that window to find the right function... does anyone know a better way ? After looking at some bug requests and more searching i couldnt seem to find any information on this and i dont find any better features for this in the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found a plugin at the vendors site that shows the functions in a nice way. The NST plugin.